# How do i get the list of people not in an inner join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the exact list
of people who are not part of an inner list. I am not sure if its another join, a NOT EXISTS or a NOT IN function that i should use:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM db.user
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT email, m.id, u.status
                  FROM db.member m
                  INNER JOIN db.user u
                  ON m.id=u.member_id
                  )
```

Unfortunately the output is blank when I run this query. Althought about 1 million rows should appear.

Comment: Some sample data and expected output would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the query below, which is including a left outer join instead

```
select distinct u.*
from db.user u
left outer join db.member m on m.id = u.member_id
where m.id is null
```

Or if u insist using inner join, then try:

```
;with cte as (
SELECT DISTINCT m.id,
FROM db.member m
INNER JOIN db.user u
ON m.id=u.member_id
)
select *
from db.users u
where u.member_id not in (select id from cte)
```

Comment: both are great and thank you for providing me with alternatives

Answer (score 1):

You have used `U` as an alias but it is not defined. Also, you don't need to JOIN when you using `EXISTS()`. This is correct usage for `EXISTS()`:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM db.user U
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM db.member m
                   WHERE m.id=u.member_id
                  )
```